# How to break page on pdf with dynamic content in jsreport

Tags: jsreport

I have a js report pdf with header and footer with dynamic content.But content are overlap on next page.Page break not working on it.

Answer (score 1):

i know this might be old but you can add

```
<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
```

before any div you want to break the page after